# Rails Console gives me a "wirble" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

```
rails-project git:creating-models ❯ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
Couldn't load Wirble: cannot load such file -- wirble
irb(main):001:0>
```

I've googled and nothing related to this shows up.. I'm not sure if this helps though

```
rails-project git:creating-models ❯ irb
>> puts $:
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wirble-0.1.3/lib
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0
```

Ruby version:

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
```

I'm using OSX, not Ubuntu (which seems to be the source of this problem on every google search I see)

Comment: just leaving this here for my own notes: `sudo gem install wirble`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you require Wirble in your .irbrc. Do you have a ~/.irbrc file? If so, removing Wirble from it (or adding Wirble to the development bundle of your app) will fix this problem.

Comment: Wow I see... what exactly is this? I am using oh-my-zsh, will that conflict with anything?

Comment: Wirble provides tab completion and syntax highlighting for irb. Shouldn't conflict with anything, it's just convenience stuff.

Comment: will that mean if i run irb in a non-rails app wirble is no longer included? that fixed it btw thanks :)

Comment: Anything you include in ~/.irbrc will be included every time you start irb, whether you start it by using the rails console or by typing irb. And no problem!

Comment: im still confused though, i mean if i remove it from IRB, does that mean it doesnt load when i use irb alone (not rails console which seems to load it by itself)

Comment: Calling "rails console" loads up an instance of irb with all your models and stuff available inside of it... So rails console is just a sugary coating over irb. That's why .irbrc is loaded in both rails console and irb itself.

Comment: I see. and then where in that stack is wirble being loaded if its not in irbrc? (thanks by the way for answering)

Comment: Hmm, if it's not in .irbrc it must be somewhere else in your load path. Trying looking in all the locations specified in [the Wirble gem](https://github.com/blackwinter/wirble)... unfortunately I can't tell you exactly where it is, since I don't know. :/

Comment: sorry i should have clarified. Wirble was inside my .irbrc, and rails console didn't work. I removed it from irbrc, and now rails console works. But now because I removed it from irbrc... when I do irb normally (not in a rails project using rails console), wirble is no longer loaded because its not in irbrc (puts $: shows no warble). How do i get it in both irb and rails console.

Comment: Oh, try doing this:

begin
  require 'wirble'
rescue
  puts "Couldn't load wirble, continuing anyway"
end

Comment: excellent, that got rails console to load now at least. Is there a way to make wirble work inside rails console now?

Comment: For future reference, the answer to Tallboy's question is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9406273/21908