# rails console with wirble?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, irb

How do i use rails console with the wirble gem? I originally had the code that wirble gives you and put it in my .irbrc

At this point, irb worked fine with wirble (color highlighting), but when i would start `rails console` it would give an error about wirble and halt.

I changed the irbrc code so it doesnt halt but continues on error, this at least gets `rails console` load but theres no color highlighting.

Any ideas what i should put? this is in my irbrc

```
begin 
  # load and initialize wirble
  require 'wirble'
  Wirble.init
  Wirble.colorize
rescue 
  puts "Couldn't load Wirble, continuing anyway"
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `gem 'wirble', :group => :development` in your `Gemfile`.

**PS**
Take a look on `Hirb` and `awesome_print` also.

Comment: BTW the best console gem for Rails id `jazz_hands` which install Pry, Hirb, awesome_print and much more.