# Using Hirb and Awesome Print with Pry Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pry, pry-rails

I've been using Pry with Rails for a while via the [Pry-Rails Gem](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails).

I want to add Hirb and Awesome Print to Pry, so I've added initialisation code to my `~/.pryrc` file as described [here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#wiki-hirb) and [here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#wiki-awesome_print):

```
# ~/.pryrc

require 'rubygems'

# Hirb for Tables

begin
  require 'hirb'

  Hirb.enable
  old_print = Pry.config.print
  Pry.config.print = proc do |output, value|
    Hirb::View.view_or_page_output(value) || old_print.call(output, value)
  end
rescue LoadError => err
  puts "no hirb :("
end

# Awesome Print

begin
  require 'awesome_print'
  Pry.config.print = proc { |output, value| output.puts value.ai }
rescue LoadError => err
  puts "no awesome_print :("
end
```

However, when I run `$rails c` Pry can't find either Hirb or Awesome print.

**Why is this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails console with wirble?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406245/rails-console-with-wirble)

Comment: did you add the gems to your Gemfile?

Comment: Did you `gem install hirb`? That was my problem when this happened.

Comment: This code worked first try for me (with the gems in my Gemfile), and with rails 5 at that